# ofstream with a custom name and path

Tags: c++

I want to make a bat file that are stored in a specific folder (`string path = "C:\Users\"`) with a name that are given by user and saved in string. How to do it?

I saw something like this on another questions:`(path\\filename)`, but in my case, the name is a string, so i don't know how to make it.

```
void BatFile()
{
    std::string filename, username;
    std::cout << "Name your save file in database:\n\n"; std::cin >> filename;
    filename = filename + ".bat";
    std::ofstream batout(filename);
    std::cout << "Username="; std::cin >> username;
    batout.open(filename);
    batout <<""; //write to bat file.
    batout.close();
}
```

I put the path in string because i don't know if i will not make to choose the user the directory where he will want to save that bat files what will be made.

Comment: unclear what you are asking. What is wrong with the code you have? In what way should it be different?

Comment: And why are you opening the file twice, not doing anything with `username`?

Comment: @user463035818 is not hard to understand. I want to make a bat file in a folder and the path for that folder are stored in string. The name is a variable given by user input.

Comment: @LogicStuff username is part of writing to batch file. Like `batout << "Stuff"<<username<<" \nStuff";` . A little mistake, now i see i'm opening the file twice.

Comment: apparently too hard for me. You are already concatenating strings in your code and you are already using a string `filename` to open the file, so I honestly do not understand what you are asking.

Comment: @user463035818 I mean, can i do something like this?: `std::ofstream batout("path\\filename")` . I don't know how to explain better.

Comment: @AmicuLL Yes you can. Have you tried it?

Comment: yes you can use a string literal as parameter when a `std::string` is expected, just as you can do `std::string filename = "path//filename"; std::ostream batout(filename);`

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé Yes.. i have tried that and is not working how i expected.

Comment: @user463035818 but if i put the string in another string, it will not take what contains that string saved. It will take it like a quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate `string`s with `+`.

Like this:

```
std::string directory = ”C:/this/that/”;
std::string name;
if (std::cin >> name)
{
    std::ofstream out(directory + name + ”.bat”);
    out << ”Hello, Joe!”;
}
```

Comment: Filenames can have spaces on Windows, so `std::getline(std::cin, name)` would make more sense than `std::cin >> name`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It’s an illustrative example, not an essay on software engineering.

Comment: It was so simple... lol. Just for 2 back slash i was researching 2 hours.I just had to add `\\` at the end of: `std::string folder = "C:\\Users\\AmicuLL\\Desktop";`
@RemyLebeau you're right, but in this case the name will be without spaces. It will be like: p1,p2 etc.